# how to get message recieve notification in flutter app

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the chatList where the contacts for chatting are shown i want to add notification recieval code for messsage receive notification but i i have no idea how since i am a beginner
i need helpso that it can be done

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/common/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/common/widgets/loader.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/features/chat/controller/chat_controller.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/features/chat/screens/mobile_chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/models/chat_contact.dart';
import 'package:chatspot/models/group.dart';

class ContactsList extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ContactsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<Group>>(
                stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).chatGroups(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Loader();
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var groupData = snapshot.data![index];

                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                MobileChatScreen.routeName,
                                arguments: {
                                  'name': groupData.name,
                                  'uid': groupData.groupId,
                                  'isGroupChat': true,
                                  'profilePic': groupData.groupPic,
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  groupData.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    groupData.lastMessage,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    groupData.groupPic,
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  DateFormat.Hm().format(groupData.timeSent),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(color: dividerColor, indent: 85),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),

            StreamBuilder<List<ChatContact>>(
                stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).chatContacts(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Loader();
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var chatContactData = snapshot.data![index];


                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                MobileChatScreen.routeName,
                                arguments: {
                                  'name': chatContactData.name,
                                  'uid': chatContactData.contactId,
                                  'isGroupChat': false,
                                  'profilePic': chatContactData.profilePic,
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  chatContactData.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    chatContactData.lastMessage,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    chatContactData.profilePic,
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  DateFormat.Hm()
                                      .format(chatContactData.timeSent),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(color: dividerColor, indent: 85),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***chatList is where is think the code is to be put for notification receive.***
***which i don't know how and i need help in that.***

this is the notification services class do that it can be used to access notification services `

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LocalNotificationService {


  static String serverKey = 'AAAAK22geOQ:APA91bHS7HGf9upOaU3BfjUjnImGMqWvxuOGyArsUfiwNhCpHnHmDCIPdByxc7av_tdGquMwoZyaYweNW55Gs21Jmv6Ieu2nN2NzaPuQRZJCYZfzDRdTL_X5nD03ZO0SZ2r9hoXBG5';

  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static void initialize() {
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"));
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async{
    try {
      print("In Notification method");
      Random random = new Random();
      int id = random.nextInt(1000);
      final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            "mychanel",
            "my chanel",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
          )

      );
      print("my id is ${id.toString()}");
      await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Error>>>$e');
    }
  }

  static Future<void> sendNotification(
      {String? title, String? message, String? token}) async {
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    print("token is $token");
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    final data = {
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "id": "1",
      "status": "done",
      'message': message
    };

    try {
      http.Response r = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':

          'key=$serverKey',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'notification': <String, dynamic>{'body': message, 'title': title},
            'priority': 'high',
            'data': data,
            "to": "$token"
          },
        ),
      );

      print(r.body);
      if (r.statusCode == 200) {
        print('DOne');
      } else {
        print(r.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('exception $e');
    }
  }


  static storeToken() async {
    try{
      String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      print(token);
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .set({'fcmToken': token!}, SetOptions(merge: true));

    }catch(e){
      print("error is $e");
    }
  }

}
```